# Nx advanced reverse proxy configuration

Tags: reactjs, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Migrating a react application to an Nx integrated workspace, and having an issue with advanced proxy configuration.

I understand that for a simple proxy...

1. Specify the proxy.conf.json file

```
"serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/webpack:dev-server",
      "defaultConfiguration": "development",
      "options": {
        "verbose": true,
        "buildTarget": "ydsca:build",
        "hmr": true,
        **"proxyConfig": "apps/ydsca/proxy.conf.json",**
        "ssl": true,
        "sslKey": "certs/localhost.key.pem",
        "sslCert": "certs/localhost.crt.pem"
      },
```

2. Implement the proxy.conf.json file, e.g....

```
{
    "/caconnect/common/*": {
        "target": "https://127.0.0.1:9443",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

This works without any issues, however, the current React application uses "http-proxy-middleware" and a more advanced setupProxy.js file (wildcard matching such as "/**/common/" for any patch that contains /common/):

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    [
      '/**/common/',
      '/**/commonClassic/',
      '/**/ydscaCommon/',
      '/ymca',
      '/staff'
    ],
    createProxyMiddleware({
      //Must use 127.0.0.1 as for some reason, localhost stopped working in node versions > 16
      target: 'https://127.0.0.1:9443',
      //Necessary for https with self signed certificates
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: false,
      //Additional logging stuff!
      onProxyReq: function onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
          // Log outbound request to remote target
          console.log('-->  ', req.method, req.path, '->', proxyReq.baseUrl + proxyReq.path);
      },
      onError: function onError(err, req, res) {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500);
          res.json({error: 'Error when connecting to remote server.'});
      },
      //logLevel: 'debug'
    })
  );
 };
```

How can the same advanced proxying be configured in Nx?

Tried changing proxyConfig": "apps/ydsca/proxy.conf.json" to proxyConfig": "apps/ydsca/setupProxy.js", but it doesn't seem to like javascript files for proxy configuration!

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First I define a local-proxy.js script that will spin up a proxy with the configuration that you previously defined for your proxy.

local-proxy.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const setupProxy = (config, port = 3000) => {
  const app = express();

  Object.keys(config).forEach((context) => {
    app.use(context, createProxyMiddleware(config[context]));
  });

  app.listen(port);
  console.log(`Proxy listening on port ${port}`);
  console.log('READY');
};

// Usage: node local-proxy.js ./path/to/proxy.config.json 3000
const proxyConfig = require(process.argv[2]);
setupProxy(proxyConfig, process.argv[3]);
```

Next I setup an NX run-command that will spin up the proxy with my configuration, this will go in your project.json or workspace.json file:

```json
        "proxy": {
            "executor": "nx:run-commands",
            "outputs": [],
            "options": {
                "readyWhen": "READY"
            },
            "configurations": {
                "development": {
                    "command": "node ./libs/utils/proxy/src/lib/local-proxy.js ./config/dev-proxy.config.json 4199 &"
                }
            }
        }
```

Next, I set up NX to run the command before the executor.
In the `nx.json` file at the root:

```json
    "targetDefaults": {
        "build": {
            "dependsOn": ["^build"]
        },
        "serve-static": {
            "dependsOn": ["proxy"]
        }
    }
```

Where `serve-static` is the executor that depends on the `proxy` command.

In the executor configuration for the file server, I specify the `proxyUrl` option for the proxy.

```
        "serve-static": {
            "executor": "@nrwl/web:file-server",
            "defaultConfiguration": "development",
            "options": {
                "buildTarget": "my-project:build",
                "port": 4201
            },
            "configurations": {
                "development": {
                    "buildTarget": "my-project:build:development",
                    "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:4199"
                }
            }
        }
```

This should spin up the proxy before it does the build and serve of the static files. If the route doesn't match any route defined in your application it will then route it to the proxy configuration to be served by your backend.